# Where to save my iOS app's save files

Tags: ios, swift

I am learning iOS file system to store my game data like saving the amount of money earned and things like this in a xml file.

The question is where should I store them?

I read this: [File System Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

And I don't know that I should save data in **Documents** directory or **Application Support** directory.

Because the data I want to save is something that is not associated with user's documents and user will never see it so it should be in Application Support, but on the other hand it's something that is affected by user interactions so it should be in Documents.

Comment: go for document directory

Comment: @iAnurag What's the problem with Application Support?

Comment: no, no, no go with Application Support, you most probably don't want the user to be able to edit/view these files right? Documents is meant for **documents** people can edit/view.

Comment: yes, I don't want the file(s) to be seen and I only edit them in background to save variables.

Comment: if your variable data is less, you can use `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: NSUserDefaults data are lost when we can uninstalled the app,so its not a preferable.

Comment: yes you are right. @KandhalBhutiya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is the **Application Support/MyGame** as per the Apple Developer guide link shared by you. You are confused by the fact that it should not be something affected by user interaction. Actually it means user should not directly interact with these. See this from the link: [File System Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW1)

[image: Application Support]

Using something like Parse may slow down your app as it needs to interact with their server, but you do get a backup.

Answer (score 0):

For something of this size, I'd use a mobile backend solutions provider like Parse or Firebase. Personally I use Parse in my projects and is very easy to implement advanced functionality into your apps like user registration/save data to users.

Hope this helps.